# How to truly remove widgets ? (widget_parent.remove_widget(child_widget_instance) not enough)

Tags: python, kivy

I have created a custom Label that removes itself when clicked on, used the `parent.remove_widget(child_instance)` method with mitigate success : the widget graphically disappear, but when my mouse hover over its position, its `on_enter` and `on_leave` hovering events do still fires...

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window


Builder.load_string("""
<DrawingSpace>:
    size_hint : None,None
    size : 1000,700
    Tag:
        id : tag_test
        pos : 100, 50
        size_hint : None,None
        size : self.texture_size
        tag : "test text"
""")


class Tag(Label):

    tag = kivy.properties.StringProperty("")
    markup = kivy.properties.BooleanProperty(True)
    hovered = kivy.properties.BooleanProperty(False)

    def __init__(s,*args,**kargs):
        s.register_event_type("on_enter")
        s.register_event_type("on_leave")
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=s.on_mouse_pos)
        Label.__init__(s,*args,**kargs)
        s._regular_text = "[color=ffffff]{}[/color]"
        s._hovered_text = "[color=ff0000][s][b]{}[/b][/s][/color]"

    def on_mouse_pos(s,*args):
        pos = args[1]
        inside = s.collide_point(*s.to_widget(*pos))
        if s.hovered == inside:
            return
        s.hovered = inside
        if inside :
            s.dispatch("on_enter")
        else :
            s.dispatch("on_leave")

    def on_touch_down(s,touch):
        if s.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            s.parent.remove_widget(s)
            del s
        return False

    def on_tag(s,instance,text):
        s.text = s._regular_text.format(s.tag)

    def on_enter(s):
        print ("on_enter:: text :",s.text)
        s.text = s._hovered_text.format(s.tag)
        pass

    def on_leave(s):
        print ("on_leave:: text :",s.text)
        s.text = s._regular_text.format(s.tag)
        pass


class DrawingSpace(RelativeLayout):
    pass


class Main(App):
    def build(s):
        return DrawingSpace()


Window.fullscreen = False
Main().run()
```

how would you proceed to actually not only remove graphically the widget instance, but completely remove it so that its event do not get computed anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this **truly** removes the widget, but if you add a call to `funbind`:

```
def on_touch_down(s,touch):
    if s.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        Window.funbind('mouse_pos', s.on_mouse_pos)
        s.parent.remove_widget(s)
        del s
    return False
```

then the `on_enter` and `on_leave` events will stop.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized before going to bed that indeed the last thing keeping the instance alive was this bind to `Window.mouse_pos`. Your answer is correct, even though the method `Window.unbind()` is enough.

Thanks again :)

Comment: I actually tried `Window.unbind()`, but that had no effect.

Comment: Hmmm... weird, it has the desired effect with me... Then I guess I should use `funbind()` as it obviously seems to cover more situations.

But I still wonder  why `unbind()` did not work with you.

Comment: Oops, `Window.unbind()` does work if I give the correct arguments.